# Python: How to Link Multi-Processes to Multi-Progress Bars

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing

It seems I've got dangerously close to being able to link all the sub-processes initiated by subprocessing's Pool() to PyQt Progress Bar widgets. Here is the example code. Apparently there are few flows that stop my dream from happening.

The concept:

externalFunc() performs all the main tasks. From time to time it sends its 'progress values' to MainWindow() instance by storing its VALUE into poolDict variable declared with:

```
poolDict=manager.dict()
```

Meanwhile myEvenListener() method is running at the background awaiting for VALUE to be 'posted'. As soon as VALUE "received"  myEvenListener() updates a ProgressBar to a received VALUE and resets it back to zero (to avoid the duplicate progressBar updates).
myEvenListener(self) before trying to update ProgressBar verifies the ProgressBar didn't yet reach its 100 maximum value before proceeding by using:

```
if pb.value()>=100: continue
```

Unfortunately even while externalFunc() supplies with more than enough values (160) the ProgressBar never reaches 100. Aside from it there is no way to exit MainWindow() while loop.

*Please be carefull running this code before you read it since it may generate multi-python-processes on your machine that will have to be terminated.*

Question:

1. Why does ProgressBar never reach its maximum 100
2. How to make sure myEvenListener() method is not running when it is not needed.
3. How to make sure all the sub-processes die after:
   a. all the progressBars  are at their 100%
   b. user closes dialog box or terminates main process.

---

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
manager = mp.Manager()

poolDict=manager.dict()

class PbWidget(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, total=20):
        super(PbWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimum(1)
        self.setMaximum(total)        
        self._active = False  

    def update_bar(self, to_add_number):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            value = self.value() + to_add_number            
            self.setValue(value)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            if (not self._active or value >= self.maximum()):                
                break
        self._active = False

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._active = False


def externalFunc(each):
    for i in range(16):
        print i
        poolDict[each]=10+i 
        time.sleep(0.5)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # self.myList=[.1, .3, .5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.9, 3.1]
        self.myList=[1]
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.pBars={}
        self.state=True

        for each in self.myList:
            pb=PbWidget(total=101)
            self.main_layout.addWidget(pb)
            self.pBars[each]={'pb':pb, 'value':0, 'total_value':0} 

        ok_button = QtGui.QPushButton("OK")
        ok_button.clicked.connect(self.OK)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(ok_button)       

        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def myEvenListener(self):
        """This function runs at the background as an infinite while loop. It constantly reads 
        a value stored in poolDict variable to which externalFunc() writes a new value every second. 
        The value represents a 'Progress' and needs to be passes to Progress Bar widget to which only MainWindow() 
        class has an access. After a Value was read it is used to update a Progress Bar. 
        After a progress bar was updated the Value is reset to zero. 
        The Problem: 'if pb.value()>=100' statement is used to make sure the function doesn't loop if the ProgressBar
        is already reached 100. By some reason the bar never reaches its maximum 100 even while externalFunc() calls
        enough times to reach this number. An ussue # 2: There is no meachanism to exit this while loop without adding
        three more variables... Can it be achieved with what we already have? 
        """
        while self.state:    
            for each in self.pBars:
                pb = self.pBars[each]['pb']
                print "\n Current Bar value =", pb.value()
                if pb.value()>=100:
                    print 'skipping'
                    continue

                value=None
                if each in poolDict.keys(): 
                    # read delivered value
                    delivered_value=poolDict[each]
                    # reset delivered value
                    poolDict[each]=0
                    # update bar with delivered value
                    if ( 101-pb.value() ) < delivered_value:
                        print "\n\t UPDATING WITH "
                        pb.update_bar( 101-pb.value() )
                        print "\n\t AFTER ", pb.value()
                    else:
                        pb.update_bar( delivered_value )
                    # print '\n\t\t\t  Updating bar using this value', delivered_value


    def OK(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=3)
        pool.map_async( externalFunc, self.myList)
        self.myEvenListener()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(480, 320)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is a revised code. It seems to be working well and it is quite stable.

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing import Pool
manager = mp.Manager()
poolDict=manager.dict()

class PbWidget(QtGui.QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, total=20):
        super(PbWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimum(1)
        self.setMaximum(total)        
        self._active = False  

    def update_bar(self, to_add_number):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            value = self.value() + to_add_number            
            self.setValue(value)
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            if (not self._active or value >= self.maximum()):                
                break
        self._active = False

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._active = False


def externalFunc(each):
    for i in range(16):
        value =10+i
        poolDict[each]=value    
        time.sleep(each)


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.myList=[.5, .8, 1.2, 1.8, 2.2, .3, .1]

        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.pBars={}
        self.state=True
        self.name=None

        for each in self.myList:
            pb=PbWidget(total=101)
            self.main_layout.addWidget(pb)
            self.pBars[each]={'pb':pb, 'name':each} 

        ok_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Distribute")
        ok_button.clicked.connect(self.OK)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(ok_button)       

        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def myEvenListener(self):
        """This function runs at the background as an infinite loop. It is constantly reading
        a value stored in poolDict variable to which externalFunc() writes a new value. 
        The value represents a 'Progress' and needs to be passed to Progress Bar widget to which MainWindow() 
        class has an access. After a Value was read and used to update a Progress Bar it is reset to zero.       
        """ 
        entities = self.pBars.keys()
        while self.state:    
            for each in entities:
                if each not in self.pBars.keys():   continue    

                pb = self.pBars[each]['pb']
                if pb.value()>=100:
                    self.pBars.pop(each, None)

                value=None
                if each in poolDict.keys():
                    # read delivered value
                    delivered_value=poolDict[each]
                    # reset delivered value
                    poolDict[each]=0
                    # update bar with delivered value
                    if ( 101-pb.value() ) < delivered_value:
                        pb.update_bar( 101-pb.value() )                     
                    elif delivered_value>0:
                        pb.update_bar( delivered_value )

                if len(self.pBars.keys())==0:
                    self.state=False

    def OK(self):       
        pool = Pool(processes=3)
        pool.map_async( externalFunc, self.myList)
        self.myEvenListener()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(480, 320)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```